# Can I close groups by default?

Tags: tfs

Using TFS 2017.3 we are trying to migrate to the new **WebLayout** for work items and run into a few issues.

One of these issues is that fields take up way more space then needed because the labels can no longer be placed on the left, but I know this is a design choice from migration.

One thing I wonder I we can do is to define a WebLayout group and by default show it as collapsed/closed by default?

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have many fields you can create 4 sections, in each section 1 group with fields. not good?

Comment: Not the ideal solution or the answer to my question, but how can we enable the 4th column ?

Comment: Just define one more `<Section> </Section>` and put there a group with fields

Comment: Thanks, should have known that :)
When creating a new work item, the Development and Related Work groups are closed by default, i would like to have this same behaviour for some other fields. Is there no way to control this ?

Comment: Are you sure the Development and Related Work groups are closed by default? I tested in our TFS and it open. try to open them, close the tab and open again, I think it will be open, I think it remembers the last change (open/close).

Comment: It indeed remembers the last state !

Comment: BTW - do you have read-only fields?

Comment: I do have some yes, why ?

Comment: You can add a rule to hides those fields when they empty

Comment: Ah yes, that one i know, thank you. the 4th column is ok for now.